# Linux kernel address. Will memory mapped IO reduce the memory I can "see"?

Tags: linux-kernel

I'm a newbie of linux kernel, I confuse the question:

Suppose I have a 32-bit PC witch 4GB memory and a vedio card witch with 1GB SDRAM internal, when I do memory mapped IO, map vedio card's 1G RAM to kernel, will I only touch 3GB memory of the memory card, and the other 1GB is untouchable until I release the IO memory map?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is: it depends on your kernel. If it does support Physical Address Extension (PAE), than you can address more than 4GB of memory, but you lose time for address translation on each memory access.

See for example: http://linuxlookup.com/howto/use_more_4gb_memory_ubuntu_linux_32_bit